# Mapping exposed ports on Bluemix containers

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I have "dockerized" a very simple nodejs application to experiment with Docker on Bluemix and in my Dockerfile I only expose port 8080 with the following directive

```
--> EXPOSE :8080
```

Now, if I run the container locally I can remap port 8080 to any other port by using -p option in docker run, as in the following example

```
--> docker run -it -p 80:8080 robitest:1
```

I have then tried to run the container on Bluemix, with the following

```
--> cf ic run -p 80:8080 registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/rpozzi/robitest:1
```

but I see the only accessible port is always 8080 (not 80)
`--> 134.168.61.240:8080->8080/tcp` (this is what I get after issuing cf ic ps command)
It looks like I cannot remap ports but Bluemix only exposes ports that have been exposed in the original Dockerfile, is this a current limitation or do I miss anything?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is correct.  The containers on bluemix do not support port remapping at this time.